# Install WSUS with remote SQL on port different to default

Tags: sql-server, wsus, sql-server-2012

How do I specify the connection parameter to a remote MSSQL Server during WSUS setup that's default instance is not running on the default port?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify a TCP connection string including the IP and port of the instance.

For example you have the MSSQL server located at: 10.0.0.10 (Port 1337) you need to specify within WSUS setup the connection string

```
tcp:10.0.0.10,1337
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a glitch with WSUS: post-install config task does not accept non-default SQL port no matter what - it will fail with error

> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): No such host is known

As a workaround, ***cliconfg*** utility  can be used to create alias:
[image]

after this you will be able feed only sql server name to WSUS, without custom port.